# Rocketjob - Help needed to initialize a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to test rocketjob by following the informations provided here: [Standalone Rocket Job Web Interface](http://rocketjob.io/installation.html)

When I visit the URL http://localhost:3000, I get the following error in my browser (Chrome):

```
NoMethodError in RocketJobMissionControl::Jobs#running
Showing /Users/arnaud.martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rocketjob_mission_control-3.2.0/app/views/layouts/rocket_job_mission_control/application.html.erb where line # raised:

undefined method `start_with?' for #<Proc:0x00007fd6b6969508>

Extracted source (around line #78):
76
77
78
79
80
81

    def valid_asset_uri?(str)
      # Quick prefix check before attempting a full parse
      str.start_with?("file://".freeze) && parse_asset_uri(str) ? true : false
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      false
    end

Rails.root: /Users/arnaud.martin/RubymineProjects/jira-rocket

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
sprockets (4.0.0) lib/sprockets/uri_utils.rb:78:in `valid_asset_uri?'
sprockets (4.0.0) lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:27:in `resolve'
sprockets (4.0.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:79:in `find_asset'
sprockets (4.0.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (4.0.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `block in synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:41:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:19:in `execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:563:in `block in realize'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:353:in `run_task'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:342:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `loop'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `catch'
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `block in create_worker'
```

I use:

- ruby 2.6.3
- Rails 6.0.2.1

and I'm working on OS X 10.15.3 (Catalina)

I tried many times but I always get the same error.